# PrimeNG how to get all Header search text with the header info

Tags: primeng, primeng-datatable

I am trying to switch my pages over to server side pagination.
We however have a global search and a header search

I need to capture the header, not sure how to capture these collectively, individually yes, but not collectively

```
  <tr>
      <th class="searchHeader" ></th>
      <th *ngFor="let col of columns" class="searchHeader" >
        <input class="fill-width" pInputText type="text" placeholder="Filter" [title]="'Type to filter ' + col.header"
          (input)="table.filter($event.target.value.trim(), this.changeColumnField(col.field), 'contains',this)">
      </th>
    </tr>
```

[image: Exampleof my UIe]